# Update a value in sql server with php that can be used one time

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to execute my update statement just once, and prevent updating it a second time. My query is as follows:

```
$sql0 = "UPDATE PRODUCTS.dbo.ITEMPRICE 
            SET Price = Price + '".$item_price."' 
          WHERE UserID = '".$session_id."'";
$q0 = odbc_exec($gcon, $sql0);
```

But every time, when I open the page, the value gets updated again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one more column to your table: *IS_UPDATED int* (0 - is not updated yet, 1 - is updated already). Set it's default value to 0.

Then your update statement will be:

```
$sql0 = "update PRODUCTS.dbo.ITEMPRICE 
            set Price = Price + '".$item_price."' 
              , IS_UPDATED = 1 
          where UserID = '".$session_id."' 
            and IS_UPDATED = 0";
```

Comment: It is just a simple approach. Actually, if you would like to post your codes, anybody else may approach you more possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works, but now i wanna try something like this
$sql01 = "SELECT Price, Code FROM PRODUCTS.dbo.ITEMPRICE WHERE UserID = '".$session_id."'";
$q01 = odbc_exec($gcon, $sql01);
IF (Code value NOT EXISTS)
{
$sql0 = "UPDATE PRODUCTS.dbo.ITEMPRICE SET Price = Price + '".$item_price."' WHERE UserID = '".$session_id."'"; 
$q0 = odbc_exec($gcon, $sql0);
}

Just wanna know what to put in if statemen to check if that code already exists in database.

Comment: In this case, you have to do two steps: 1) Check value of the code; 2) Update table if code value is 0. In my case it is just one step: 1) update table if code value is 1 (otherwise, it will not update)

Comment: so, how to do that? update table if code value is 1 (otherwise, it will not update)

Comment: Just use my statement in my answer

Comment: let's say he gets a code "123456" , i need to check if that code exists in database, if not exists, exec $sql0. and when he gets a new code "789" to check again, if not exists update database again.

Comment: Column IS_UPDATED means, were your column updated or no. (0 (make it as default value) means, that record was not updated; 1 - it was updated). So the query do: if IS_UPDATED = 0, it updates your price and set IS_UPDATED to 1; if IS_UPDATED = 1, it will not update your record.

Comment: create table codes(id int not null primary key auto_increment, code int, user_id int); --creating table for codes

Comment: $sql0 = "update PRODUCTS.dbo.ITEMPRICE 
            set Price = Price + '".$item_price."'
          where UserID = '".$session_id."' 
            and (select count(1) from codes where code = '".$your_code_value"' and user_id = '".$session_id."') = 0;";

Comment: So, you don't need IS_UPDATED anymore. This query will do: 1) check, is your code exists in the table (over counting); 2) if it does not exists, it will not update. So, in order to update just one time, you have to keep his code and don't delete that from the table

Comment: Anyway, It is just an one of solutions.